# Toggle parent class of checkbox on check action using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I am trying to make a form with multiple checkboxes. I want to highlight the checkboxes with their content to indicate to the user of the selection
I am using the following layout for my form

### HTML

```
<form>
<div class=labl>
<input type=checkbox id='alpha' />
<label for='alpha'>Checkbox1</label>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.labl{

height:50px;
}
.labl:hover{
background:#ccc;
}
.chked {
background: #4285f4;
height:50px;
}
```

### jQuery

```
<script>

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("chked");
});

</script>
```

Now when alpha is checked it should change the class of div from labl to chked
but it is not

Comment: Seems to work to me: http://jsfiddle.net/EcCr3/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/EcCr3 is working but it does not work in my code. 
my code is at http://techvisionblog.in/ipscan/facebook.html

Comment: @AshmeetSingh i see no checkbox on that website

Comment: they are added dynamically after facebook login is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DOM ready handler like this `$(function(){...});`

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("chked");
    });
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**Update**

It appears that the checkbox is dynamically added to the DOM so you must use event delegation like this

```
    $(document).on("change","input[type=checkbox]",function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("chked");
    });
```

Comment: @AshmeetSingh what exactly is not working? Is it doing nothing or doing something unexpected? Also check console for any errors.

Comment: nothing is working. the page is acting as if there is no jQuery script 
you can see my page at http://techvisionblog.in/ipscan/facebook.html

Comment: @AshmeetSingh there are no checkboxs in the link

Comment: you have to login from via facebook to see the checkboxes but the javascripts are there.
checkboxes will appear after facebook login is compelete

Comment: @AshmeetSingh are the checkboxes dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: @AshmeetSingh I've updated the answer, it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both the class names to the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method, so that only one of the will be applied at a time

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("labl chked");
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Bh7x/)

Comment: it seems to be working in fiddle but not in my code. 
In my code it appears just as if there is no jQuery
my code is at http://techvisionblog.in/ipscan/facebook.html

Comment: @AshmeetSingh there is no checkbox element in your page

Answer (score 0):

just change your script to

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $(this).parents('.labl').toggleClass("chked");
});
```

And your HTML to

```
<form>
<div class='labl'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='alpha'></input>
<label for='alpha'>Checkbox1</label>
</div>
```

Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/k242J/

Comment: it seems to work fine over here but in my own script it is not working at all
my script is at http://techvisionblog.in/ipsacn/facebook.html

Comment: Where is the checkbox on your site?

Comment: they are added dynamically after login from facebook is completed

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass functionality is to check the class, if not there it will add, else remove class thats it. its not to change from one class to another.

**css**

```
.chked {
    background: #4285f4;
}
```

**js**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
     $(this).parent().toggleClass("chked");
 });
```

Comment: toggleClass can be used to change one class to another